# log4net:ERROR ConfigureFromXml called with null 'element' parameter

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net

We are using log4net library with .NET Core for writing logs in file. But we are getting this error when executing the application "log4net:ERROR ConfigureFromXml called with null 'element' parameter".
Here is our Program.cs file:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument log4netConfig = new XmlDocument();
        log4netConfig.Load(File.OpenRead("log4net.config"));
        var repo = log4net.LogManager.CreateRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), typeof(log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy));
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(repo, log4netConfig["log4net"]);

        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Here is Configure method in Startup.cs file:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Trace);
        loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
    }
```

Here is log4net.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821" />
  </configSections>

  <!-- Log4net Logging Setup -->
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="c:\LogFiles\Applications\IdentityServer\log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace your log4net.config with below code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    <file value="C:\Temp\" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd.'txt'"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="100"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="15MB"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level App  %newline %message %newline %newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: thanks @Deepak, its working fine after replacing the log4net.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, the accepted response is not accurate, the problem with the XML is the .NET configuration on top of log4net configuration. The original configuration file is a .NET configuration file instead of a log4net one, and it's rooted with a **configuration** node instead of with a **log4net** node.

The second configuration XML on the other hand is correct, but it's replacing the original configuration (maybe with a better one, for sure), not only fixing the problem but replacing the original configuration with a new one.

The a better response for the change would be:

1. Remove the **configuration** root node from the original xml file together with the **configSections** node and leave the log4net node as root of the XML resulting in:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <!-- Log4net Logging Setup -->
   <log4net>
     <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender,log4net">
       <file value="c:\LogFiles\Applications\IdentityServer\log.txt" />
       <appendToFile value="true" />
       <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
       <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
         <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
       </layout>
       <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
         <levelMin value="INFO" />
         <levelMax value="FATAL" />
       </filter>
     </appender>

     <root>
       <level value="DEBUG"/>
       <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
     </root>
   </log4net>
   ```
2. Reconfigure your appender with a Rolling appender if needed...

Comment: THANK YOU for this. This is still relevant for a .NET 6 console application using the CreateDefaultBuilder host.